# XNA 4.0 online server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, xna, xmlhttprequest

How do I make a server for my game so you can download maps? Each map will be an XML document, but I want to have the server be in-game, instead of on a website. I do have some experience with HTML/PHP, but very little. There will be no multiplayer interaction (that I have planned), it's all going to be singleplayer.

Another thing is how to have variables attached to it, like reviews that you can see before you download it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to program your own server.exe and run it from a accessible machine. Whenever someone wants to DL new maps, they will exchange communications with this server.exe that will supply the reviews/download times and other variables that you want to display.

Is this Windows-only? If so, you can use Lidgren network lib (http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/). If not youre stuck with the internal network library.

You dont need HTML/PHP since you dont want it to be a website.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is there any non-Windows only service like the one you put up? It is Windows only, but I may want to do something non-Widows only at some point. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to do something non-Windows using XNA you can only do it for Xbox and Windows Phone at the time. And on those XNA is restricted to using the Xbox Live Gaming Services. You cannot connect to any outside services at all.

Comment: Well, what about non-XNA things? QT or something?

Comment: @Halleflux I doubt that there will be a online server to do this kind of request that you want, since it is a bit specific. But there are ones that store highscore tables and such, like OpenFeint [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFeint). You gonna have to do it on your own. I did a quick google search and found this [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-fortuneserver.html), since I dont have any QT experience.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm not sure what I'm going to be doing after this, so I want to prepared. Thanks!

Comment: In regards to the cross platform thing... if you're using XNA then you'll probably looking at Monogame for that, and that can use Lidgren for networking too.